# C++ Regular expression on multiple buffers

Tags: c++, regex

I have a sort of problem with regex, I want it to count multiple (well, in this case, one) buffer as one string.

Let's say I download a file and I want to search for a specific string, let's say "foobar".
I don't know what the file size will be and I don't want to allocate a huge chunk of couple megabytes of buffer for html code.

So, the idea is, I have this small buffer, lets say 64 bytes.
Let's say we write a chunk of that file and the char array looks like this

```
.............foobar.............
```

Everything seems fine, but if the array was like this

```
.............................foo
```

And on the other write of chunk it becomes

```
bar.............................
```

The problem is self explanatory. Regex will not find the strings on separate checks. We could allocate big buffer size to contain page at once, but that's a huge waste.

So, I have an idea - split buffers. Let's say on first write we get these buffers

```
 ............................foo
 ------------------------------- // this one is empty
```

then, after second write we get this

```
 ............................foo
 bar............................
```

now, if there was a regex function that would count these buffers as one that would be great. I could simply keep alternating the buffers and pull the strings I want to without allocating a lot of space in ram.

Is there a c++ regex library that would do that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::regex_match` (available since C++11, see header `<regex>`) has an interface that takes a pair of iterators delimiting the "string" to search in. You could create your own iterator class which would simply iterate over the collection of buffers sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

After each alternation of the buffers you could concatenate the buffers into a temp buffer and then search using the regex.  ie. for every pair of reads.

Comment: Yeah, I know, its simple, but I'm sort of a performance freak and I want to copy stuff to temp buffers as less as I can. I will do that unless I don't find a way to feed these two buffers to regex at once.